# Book on historic experiments

Tags: resource-recommendations, history

I am looking for a book which describes in a detailed way the most important experiments in the history of physics.

I was googling for it but could not find a satisfactory result. Either the books are too basic with no background required or too detailed on specific methods.

Any recommendations would be welcome.

Comment: [Great Experiments in Physics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Great_Experiments_in_Physics/J0fCAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try [*The Ten Most Beautiful Experiments*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ten-Most-Beautiful-Experiments/dp/0099464586) by George Johnson.

Amongst others, it includes chapters on Galileo's inclined plane experiment; Newton's experiments with prisms; Michelson's speed of light experiments and Millikan's oil drop experiment.